# ValueError: Unknown layer: QuantizeLayer

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

After QAT training with tensorflow_model_optimization followed the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/training_comprehensive_guide#quantize_whole_model)

then use Keras to load the quantized model will show **Unknown layer: QuantizeLayer**

```
   tf.keras.models.load_model(keras_quantized_model_file)
```

Answer (score 11):

The problem solved by the following code:

```py
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot

with tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_scope():
    loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(keras_quantized_model_file)
```